# Branching with Django Form Wizard

Tags: django, forms, branch, django-formwizard

Is there a way that in Django you branch to a different existing FormWizard from the option you select on a previous page?

Like an example I have two FormWizard called `PizzaForm` and `SandwichForm`. The first page ask if you want pizza or sandwich and the option you select calls the Form Wizard depending what you select.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in view of first form. somethings like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def firts_page_view(request):
    if request.POST.get('pizza', None):
        form = PizzaForm()
        template_name = 'pizza_template.html'
    else:#sandwich
        form = SandwichForm()
        template_name = 'sandwich_template.html'
    return render_to_response( 'sandwich.html', {'form': form} )
```

Comment: I assuming PizzaForm() is part of a Form Wizard or is the name of a list?

Comment: you can handle this in `tamplete`. create both `Pizza` & `Sandwich` list in form. and based on condition set a falg. and in template you can use this flag to show desired list.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible using the condition_dict.  Basically you create methods which return booleans to dictate form flow.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/